# One Record Two Point Geometries - Point-in-polygon

Tags: postgis, spatial-join, point-in-polygon, spatial-query

The trip data contains the origin-destination of each trip, and both origin and destination are stored as geometries. How could I retrieve the origin and destination polygons that the points are located?

The following code works fine to find the polygon which the origin is located. I need to determine the destination_polygon as well.

```
SELECT p.id as origin_polygon
FROM trips t, polygons p
WHERE ST_Contains(p.geom, t.origin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **INNER JOIN** to get the polygons for the origin and target at the same time:

```
SELECT p1.id as original_polygon , p2.id as destination_polygon
FROM trips t 
INNER JOIN polygons p1 ON ST_Contains(p1.the_geom, t.origin)
INNER JOIN polygons p2 ON ST_Contains(p2.the_geom, t.destination)
```